# React Select - How to show / iterate through data from JSON data in option instead of hardcoding options?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, select, react-select

I'm using react-select in my application and I don't want to hard code the options to select from but instead use the JSON file in my program, I found out how to display Json data in a table earlier and implemented and I feel like it's related to this in some way. Hope you guys can help me out.

**Dashboard.js**

```
**function Dashboard() {
  const DisplayData = JsonData.map(
    (info) => {
      return (
        <tr>
          <td>{info.PRODUCT}</td>
          <td>{info.QUANTITY}</td>
          <td>{info.CLIENTNAME}</td>
          <td>{info.UNITS}</td>
        </tr>
      )
    }
  );

  return (
    <>
      <div className="content">
        <Row>
          <Col md="12">
            <Card>
              <CardHeader>
                <CardTitle tag="h4">Inventory</CardTitle>
              </CardHeader>
              <CardBody>
                <Table className="tablesorter" responsive>
                  <thead className="text-primary">
                    <tr>
                      <th>PRODUCT</th>
                      <th>QUANTITY</th>
                      <th>CLIENTNAME</th>
                      <th>UNITS</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>

                    {DisplayData}

                  </tbody>
                </Table>
              </CardBody>
            </Card>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default Dashboard;**
```

**Orders.js**

```
    function Order() {

  return (
    <>
      <div className="content">
        <Row>
          <Col md="6">
            <Card>
              <CardHeader>
                <CardTitle tag="h4">Order Form</CardTitle>
              </CardHeader>
              <CardBody>
                <form action="#">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
                      <label class="font-weight-bold text-small" for="firstname">First name<span class="text-primary ml-1">*</span></label>
                      <select width="200" >
                        <option value="PH">PH</option>
                        <option value="PD">PD</option>
                        <option value="XI">XI</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </form>
              </CardBody>
            </Card>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default Order;
```

**data.json**

```
    {
        "ROWID": "000186E6-5",
        "BINLABEL": "RECEIVE",
        "PRODUCT": "PR0001",
        "QUANTITY": "20.000000",
        "PACKSIZE": "1.000000",
        "UNALLOC": "20.000000",
        "USER_ID": "CARLOS",
        "CLIENT": "",
        "COUNTED": "0.000000",
        "EXTENDED": "PR0001    ",
        "PO_NUM": "300-1",
        "RECV_SLIP": "",
        "RETURN_BIN": "",
        "WAREHOUSE": "LKT",
        "COMMENT_IN": "",
        "RESERVED": "",
        "DATECREATE": "2022-01-27",
        "TOWER": "",
        "MODIFIED": 0,
        "RECV_PONUM": "",
        "LINE_NUM": "",
        "CLIENTNAME": "KAR",
        "TENANTID": "",
        "DATE_TIME": "20220127 1",
        "CNT_USER_ID": "~",
        "LICENSE_PLATE": "",
        "TRANSFER": "300-1",
        "TIMECREATE": "",
        "PO_LINE_UNIT_COST": "0.000000",
        "ADDED_UNIT_COST": "0.000000",
        "TOTAL_UNIT_COST": "0.000000",
        "BINTYPE": "S",
        "FROM_BIN": "C05B06",
        "INNERPACK": 1,
        "LOCATION": "LKT",
        "MAX_PACK": 0,
        "MIN_PACK": 0,
        "PUSHBACK": 0,
        "ZONE": "",
        "IS_BONDED": "",
        "EXTRA1": "",
        "EXTRA2": "",
        "VEND_NUM": "",
        "DATE_RECVD": "NULL",
        "DATE_SHIPPED": "NULL",
        "PACKSLIP": "",
        "ORDER_SEQ": "",
        "CUST_NUM": "",
        "SO_LINE_UNIT_PRICE": "0.000000",
        "GROSS_PROFIT": "0.000000",
        "PROD_CLASS": "",
        "SALESMAN": "",
        "BUYER": "",
        "DOCUMENT_REF": "",
        "UNITS": "20.000000"
    },
    {
        "ROWID": "1639004C-9",
        "BINLABEL": "#0000170",
        "PRODUCT": "DEMO 01",
        "QUANTITY": "1000.00000",
        "PACKSIZE": "1.000000",
        "UNALLOC": "0.000000",
        "USER_ID": "HH",
        "CLIENT": "",
        "COUNTED": "0.000000",
        "EXTENDED": "DEMO 01   ",
        "PO_NUM": "149-1",
        "RECV_SLIP": "",
        "RETURN_BIN": "",
        "WAREHOUSE": "",
        "COMMENT_IN": "",
        "RESERVED": "",
        "DATECREATE": "2022-06-15",
        "TOWER": "",
        "MODIFIED": 0,
        "RECV_PONUM": "",
        "LINE_NUM": "",
        "CLIENTNAME": "SAOUD",
        "TENANTID": "",
        "DATE_TIME": "20220615 1",
        "CNT_USER_ID": "~",
        "LICENSE_PLATE": "",
        "TRANSFER": "",
        "TIMECREATE": "",
        "PO_LINE_UNIT_COST": "0.000000",
        "ADDED_UNIT_COST": "0.000000",
        "TOTAL_UNIT_COST": "0.000000",
        "BINTYPE": "S",
        "FROM_BIN": "P01B01",
        "INNERPACK": 1,
        "LOCATION": "",
        "MAX_PACK": 0,
        "MIN_PACK": 0,
        "PUSHBACK": 0,
        "ZONE": "#",
        "IS_BONDED": "",
        "EXTRA1": "",
        "EXTRA2": "",
        "VEND_NUM": "",
        "DATE_RECVD": "NULL",
        "DATE_SHIPPED": "NULL",
        "PACKSLIP": "",
        "ORDER_SEQ": "",
        "CUST_NUM": "",
        "SO_LINE_UNIT_PRICE": "0.000000",
        "GROSS_PROFIT": "0.000000",
        "PROD_CLASS": "",
        "SALESMAN": "",
        "BUYER": "",
        "DOCUMENT_REF": "",
        "UNITS": "1000.00000"
    }
```

This is the code I'm using, Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yo!** So I figured out how to do it. Similar to what Ahammed did in their answer. I created a data.js file and I put all the data in it & then I imported this data as options in Order.js. Then I used the code below:

```
<div class="form-group col-lg-2">
 <label class="font-weight-bold text-small" for="Product">Product<span class="text-primary ml-1">*</span></label>
   <select required="" class="form-control"  >
      <option selected disabled="true">-- Choose Product --</option>
          {options.map((option) => (
           <option value={option.PRODUCT}>{option.PRODUCT}</option>
       ))}
  </select>
</div>
```

I think what the code does is map the data from data.js on `<option>` allowing us to access the data through the dot notation.

**Thank you!** I hope this was helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a data.ts file and put your data inside that and export that file.

In React app you can import and use it.

```
import Select from "react-select";
import { options } from "./data";

export default () => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState<any>({});

  return (
    <>
      <Select
        name="code"
        options={options}
        value={value}
        onChange={setValue}
        getOptionLabel={(option) => option.code}
        getOptionValue={(option) => option.code}
      />
    </>
  );
};


// data.ts

export const options = [
  {
    code: "PH"
  },
  {
    code: "PD"
  },
  {
    code: "XI"
  }
];
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! I wanna ask tho, so by putting my data in a data.ts file do you mean i just put my json data in the data.ts file? how does that make it different to just using my Json data in data.json? Also the code you provided above goes into App.js right? I'm kind of confused on how it works. Thank you again!

Comment: If you use data.ts/data.js then you can export it as constant and use it in your components. If you use data.json you need an HTTP GET call to get the data. The above code you can use in any component, it is not specific for App.js. Just import `import { options } from "./data";` in your component and add `options` to the Select component.